# Combining a dacpac and a SQL Server project to update one target database

Tags: visual-studio-2015, deployment, sql-server-2012, upgrade, dacpac

I have a database that is created by a third party tool. The schema is updated regularly so I need to send updates to my production environment.
We're developing some views on top of this database. For these views I'm using a Database Project. In this project I reference a DACPAC I created from the third party database.

When I'm going to deploy the complete solution I would like to deploy an automatically generated single DACPAC or upgrade script. Is there any way I can combine these two schema's upfront to make the deployment to production any easier?

So far I tried to reference the DACPAC from the third party database inside my database project, but when I build my solution I get two DACPAC files. Deploying the first DACPAC to my production environment results in deletion of views and stored procedures not in this first package. 
Disabling deletes during package deployment makes it impossible to remove objects from my solution, unless I write specific scripts for these deletes, which I would prefer not to do.

And when the second package is deployed I get the same issue.

I tried to run a schema compare between my local project and the DACPAC created from the third party database. This results in a script to add my views and stored procedures to the target schema, but not one integrated packages that I can compare to my current production environment for upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify thwhat option IncludeCompositeObjects=True and the referenced dacpac will also be deployed.

Only thing to be aware of is that pre/post deploy scripts (if any) in the referenced dacpac are ignored so you need to copy them into your main dacapac.

Ed